# Is there a Firefox plugin/extension for doc files?

Tags: browser, browser-addons, plugins, microsoft-word, documents

There are plugins to view PDF files in-browser, without downloading. Is there an equivalent for doc/docx files? I'm on a Mac, although Windows is fine too.

Answer (score 2):

[ThinkfreeFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/9327) is an experimental plugin.
Here is a [reference to it](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2008/10/29/firefox-add-on-download-thinkfree-viewer-to-view-any-document-without-installing-office-suite/),

> To open document by using ThinkFree Viewer, just right click on the document link, then choose “View with ThinkFree” as appear on the context menu. It will take some times to load and display the document in Firefox browser. From the viewer, you can format the document displayed such as change the font size or color, add table, bullets and numbering, borders and sharing, copy, cut, insert page numbers, date/time, send to printer for printing and etc. ThinkFree Viewer is specially designed with the interface as similar to Microsoft Office, so you wouldn’t feel that it is too tough to start up with.
>
> Currently ThinkFree Viewer is still under initial experiment stage and there are different versions of ThinkFree Viewer being developed to support different version of Firefox browsers.

Answer (score 2):

OpenOffice.org has a Firefox browser plugin, and it obviously opens MS Word DOC files: http://mozillalinks.org/wp/2007/09/openofficeorg-documents-within-firefox/

Answer (score 1):

You can install [mozplugger](http://mozplugger.darwinports.com/) on a mac, which will allow you to use almost any program inside a Firefox window to display almost any kind of document. You could, for example, use [AbiWord](http://abisource.org) or [Libre Office](http://www.documentfoundation.org/) to display Word (.doc) files. (Maybe Word itself, but I think Word itself provides its own plugin for this...)

Answer (score 0):

Think [Open in browser](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8207) will do it.

> Have you ever been annoyed when you wanted to see a document and the download popup appears which forces you to select an external application to view it?
>
> This extension allows you to open the
> document directly in browser. You can
> also change the mime type of a
> document being viewed.

For Firefox.

Comment: I don't see the option for Word documents... Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this just a little bit on addons.mozilla.org a while back. The extension I liked best was Open IT Online. It's chief advantage, as I saw things, was that it adds Open IT Online as an option for opening in the download dialog, meaning that you don't have to go through the context menu to use it (although you can). I have it set to open everything it can in the Google Docs Viewer, but others, like Zoho, are also supported.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/open-it-online/